# how to upload audio file to google drive with url with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, twilio

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong. I'm trying to upload a audio file to my Google drive with Google apps script. The file uploads but I can't play it.

Here is my function:

```
function upload() {
    
  var url = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Recordings/RExxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
  
    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob().getBytes();

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');  
  blob = Utilities.newBlob(blob, 'audio/x-wav', 'testFile.wav');
  var file = folder.createFile(blob); 
}
```

Comment: From `The file uploads but I can't play it.`, it is considered that the downloaded data might no invalid. So please check the downloaded data using `console.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText())` instead of `var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob().getBytes()`? By this, the raw data can be checked. If this data is not the data you expect, it is required to check the method for requesting. If my understanding of your situation is not correct, I apologize.

Comment: Or, when you test `var file = folder.createFile(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob())`, what result will you obtain?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike Thanks again for your intrest in helping me AGAIN. this is the result I get ` RIFF�`

Comment: @Tanaike here is the URL maybe you can figure out whats wrong here (its a few second blank audio file) `https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC65183d44bed255a1288b16e8d0acfe86/Recordings/REd2446c26a5bc3e86a1a2ab42a0a95683`

Comment: @Tanaike and when I check the second thing I get (truncated) `{ toString: [Function],
  getOwner: [Function],
  setContent: [Function],
  getMimeType: [Function],
  getThumbnail: [Function],
  getEditors: [Function],
  getTargetId: [Function],
  makeCopy: [Function]}`

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your sample URL, when I tested `DriveApp.createFile(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC65183d44bed255a1288b16e8d0acfe86/Recordings/REd2446c26a5bc3e86a1a2ab42a0a95683').getBlob())`, a wav file is ceated to the root folder. Is this the result you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike as I said the file gets created but it seems corrupted as i can't play it or download it so its useless

Comment: @Tanaike it ended up being a browser issue see answer below. thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *problem* here is not with the snippet of code you are using - since the file is indeed uploaded properly, but with the browser and third party cookies.

In order for the audio to be played, third party cookies should be enabled for your browser since Google Drive is not able to play the files by itself.

Another option is to simply choose one of the third party apps suggested by Google in order to play the audio file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that did it, since I was working in a incognito browser, chrome was blocking Third party cookies. Thanks @Tanaike for your input and effort